# jQuery append / prepend not working in Edge?

Tags: jquery

This piece of code takes the content of the TH (.table-dates) and moves it to a span (.date-span) inside the TD (.table-times) below it.

It works great in everything except older versions of Edge, the latest version is actually fine. Anyone any idea why this would be the case? My research is bringing up very little. The span just remains empty!

```
$(".table-dates").each(function(i,e) {
    var elem = $("<span/>").append($(e).html());
    $("table").find(".table-times .date-span")[i].prepend(elem.html());
});
```

Comment: What is the content of the `th`? Is it valid `span` content? What's `.date-span`? Is it valid to put a `span` inside it? (If it's a span, the answer is yes, but...)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder The TH simply contains plain text i.e.
<th class="table-dates">Tue 14 August</th>
and I am moving it to a td like so... <td class="table-times"><span class="date-span">Tue 14 August</span></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're (presumably-inadvertently) relying on the DOM element having a`prepend` method, because you're indexing into the jQuery object from `find` with `[i]` and then calling `prepend` on that directly:

```
$("table").find(".table-times .date-span")[i].prepend(elem.html());
// Here ----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Indexing into a jQuery object like that gives you the raw element at that index (not a jQuery object). You should be getting an error in the console about `prepend` not being a function when it fails.

The [`prepend` method](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-prepend) on the [`ParentNode` interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#parentnode) is fairly new. Apparently earlier versions of Edge didn't support it.

To use jQuery's `prepend` instead, use `eq(i)` instead of `[i]`:

```
$("table").find(".table-times .date-span").eq(i).prepend(elem.html());
// ----------------------------------------^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect, it now works in the last three versions of Edge. Also thanks for the detailed explanation of where I was going wrong, really helpful!

Comment: @ultrarun - A pleasure. And TIL that DOM elements recently got a `prepend` method (at first I thought: "Why isn't he/she **always** getting an error? Oh...I wonder..." and went looking ;-) ).